# Añadir la librería "libpqxx" a mi proyecto con CMake

Tags: c++, postgresql, cmake

Estoy tratando de aprender a usar CMake con mis proyectos de C++. En una de mis pruebas me ha surgido un problema.

Tengo mi proyecto hiper-mega-simple de C++ que se conecta a una base de datos PostgresSQL. Para ello he instalado en mi sistema Ubuntu 18.04 la librería `libpqxx` y en el CMakeLists.txt de mi proyecto la he enlazado sin problema.

Mi proyecto es el siguiente:

```
accesToDB
    ├── build/
    │   ├── CMakeCache.txt
    │   ├── CMakeFiles/
    │   ├── cmake_install.cmake
    │   ├── compile_commands.json
    │   ├── Makefile
    │   └── testPSQL   // Mi ejecutable de pruebas
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── main.cpp
    ├── modules/
    ├── test/
    │   └── CMakeLists.txt
    └── thirdparty/
        └── libpqxx/  // Carpeta de la librería con toda su mandanga
```

En la carpeta `modules` irían los módulos que yo cree para mi programa. En `test` los archivos que implemente para los test unitarios. En `thirdparty` es donde coloco las librerías y código que no he escrito yo mismo.

Mi archivo `main.cpp` es tan básico como esto:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <pqxx/pqxx>

/*
 * Archivo de prueba de una conexión con C++ estándar con PostgreSQL
 */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    try
    {
        if (1 < argc)
        {
            testFunc(atoi(argv[1]));
        }

        pqxx::connection connect("dbname=pegasusdatabase32 hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5432 user=postgres password=12345abc");
        std::cout << "Connected to " << connect.dbname() << std::endl;
        pqxx::work W(connect);

        pqxx::result R = W.exec("SELECT var_name FROM conf_resources order by id asc;");

        std::cout << "Found " << R.size() << " resources: " << std::endl;
        for (auto row : R)
            std::cout << row[0].c_str() << std::endl;

        std::cout << "Making changes definite: ";
        W.commit();
        std::cout << "OK." << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Simplemente se conecta a la base de datos de pruebas que tengo y hace una consulta muy sencilla. Además es casi una copia y pega del código de ejemplo que tiene la librería en su documentación.

Este es el CMakeLists.txt de mi proyecto:

```bsh
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)

# Set language to use: C++
enable_language(CXX)

# Setting variables
set (testRasp_VERSION_MAJOR 1)
set (testRasp_VERSION_MINOR 0)

# -- FLAGS DE COMPILACIÓN
set (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
set (CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

# IF IT ISN'T CROSS-COMPILING...
if(NOT EXISTS "${CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE}")
    set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17")
    set (CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
    message("Se compila para Linux")
endif()

project(testPSQL)

# -- INCLUDE libpqxx LIBRARY TO PROJECT
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -lpqxx -lpq")
set (PQXX /usr/local/include/pqxx)
find_library(PQXX_LIB pqxx)
find_library(PQ_LIB pq)

add_executable(testPSQL main.cpp)

target_link_libraries (testPSQL ${PQXX_LIB} ${PQ_LIB})
```

Funciona como se espera.

Problema con el que me encuentro. Me he descargado el código fuente de `libpqxx`, lo he compilado para mi máquina de desarrollo y lo he instalado.

Peeeeero... tal como tengo mi archivo CMakeLists.txt principal si quisiera exportar el proyecto a otras plataformas como Windows, Mac OS o a una Raspberry Pi 3 u otro sistema embebido no puedo. Estoy usando la librería compilada para mi sistema de desarrollo. NO compilo la librería `libpqxx` cada vez que compilo mi proyecto.

***¿Cómo he de modificar mi CMakeLists.txt principal para incluir el código fuente de la librería y que se compile para cada una de las plataformas que yo desee?***

Por favor, recordad que mis nociones de CMake son muy básicas aun.

Comment: jejejejeje no respondáis todos de golpe ni tan rápido por favor.... que no me da tiempo a leerlo todo XD

Comment: Vengaaa ánimo! que seguro que hay alguien que puede aportar algo. Yo estoy investigando y me da que los tiros van por usar `ExternalProject_Add` pero no se muy bien cómo se emplea. Consigo descargarme el proyecto del repositorio GitHub, pero al compilarlo obtengo errores y no consigo enlazarlo a mi proyecto.

Comment: Si no compilas las librerias a la vez que el proyecto, puedes tener las librerias compiladas para los diferentes sistemas, y crear enlaces , segun el sistema origen para que linke con la libreria compilada para la plataforma x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

¡Eureka! ¡Encontré la solución!

He encontrado la manera de incluir la librería, pero además, que se descargue automáticamente desde su repositorio GitHub.

La configuración que tenía anteriormente es ideal para emplear las librerías que ***ya están instaladas en el sistema***, pero no sirve si quiero compilar todo para diferentes plataformas.

Con la configuración anterior tendría que ir descargando me el código de todas y cada una de las librerías que quisiera utilizar e ir compilando una a una para cada plataforma.

### Cómo implementarlo

He realizado los siguientes pasos:

#### 1. Actualizar CMake

A partir de la versión 3.11 se añade una nueva funcionalidad muy molona: "FetchContent". Yo estaba usando la versión 3.10 por lo que he tenido que descargarme los fuentes de CMake, compilarlos e instalarlo. Algo muy trivial y fácil de hacer siguiendo las instrucciones que dan la documentación.

"FetchContent" básicamente lo que hace es descargarse del repositorio o la URL que se le indique el código fuente, lo guarda donde le digamos y finalmente lo compila junto con nuestro proyecto.

#### 2. Configurar mi CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.3)

# Set language to use: C++
enable_language(CXX)

# Setting variables
set (testRasp_VERSION_MAJOR 1)
set (testRasp_VERSION_MINOR 0)

# -- FLAGS DE COMPILACIÓN
set (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
set (CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

# IF IT ISN'T CROSS-COMPILING...
if(NOT EXISTS "${CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE}")
    set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17")
    set (CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
    message("Se compila para Linux")
endif()

project(testPSQL)

# -- Add libpqxx library
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(libpqxx
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/jtv/libpqxx.git
    GIT_TAG master
    SOURCE_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty/libpqxx
    BINARY_DIR ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/thirdparty/libpqxx
)

FetchContent_GetProperties(libpqxx)

if (NOT libpqxx_POPULATE)
    FetchContent_Populate(libpqxx)
    add_subdirectory(${libpqxx_SOURCE_DIR} ${libpqxx_BINARY_DIR})
endif()

# Create App
#-----------------------------------------------
add_executable(app main.cpp)

# Link our Application with our modules
#-----------------------------------------------
target_link_libraries(app pqxx)

# Include subdirectories
#-----------------------------------------------
target_include_directories(
    app
    PUBLIC
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty/libpqxx
)
```

Espero que os ayude.